# LaunchAgent doesn't run shell script

Tags: macos, shell, zsh, launch-agent

Under macOS prior to Catalina I had a LaunchAgent that ran a shell script daily. After upgrading and switching to zsh it doesn't work. Things I've checked:

1. shebang switched to zsh
2. shell script can be executed manually from command line
3. sh has full disk access under System Preferences > Security & Privacy
4. plist is in `~/Library/LaunchAgents` and starts automatically, so chown is OK

I added an error check to my plist:

```
<key>StandardOutPath</key>
<string>/path/to/file.out</string>
<key>StandardErrorPath</key>
<string>/path/to/file.err</string>
```

and this gives `file.err` that reads

`zsh: can't open input file: /path/to/script.sh`

`file.out` is empty. My script has permissions `-rwxr-xr-x`

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried adding zsh to Full Disk Access, or alternatively use /bin/sh in the shebang assuming your script conforms to sh? Even though the default shell has been changed in macOS, bash is still available and can be used at present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After suggestions from TheDarkKnight, I added full disk access for zsh - no success. Solution was to switch the shebang back to /bin/bash and gave Full Disk Access to bash. The script now runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as @quantixed on Monterey but for me, dragging /bin/zsh into the Full Disk Access list, like @TheDarkKnight suggested, made launchctl run the script like it should.